# IOS 9 not asking permission for remote notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, remote-notifications

I have a problem when trying to ask permission for remote notifications.

It works flawlessly on iOS 10 but when I try to do it on an iOS 9 device it doesn't show any alert and the UIApplication delegate method "application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:" isn't called. Neither the "failed" method.

I'm only testing on real devices, not simulator. The code I currently use for asking permission is the following:

```
-(void)requestPushPermissions {
NSLog(@"Starting register for remote Notification");
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10.0) {
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"Got a yes!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Got a no...");
        }
    }];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
}
```

Anybody got a clue?

Comment: are you working on device or simulator? remember that notifications don't work well on simulator

Comment: @RicardoAlves As I wrote in the question; I only test on real devices, not the simulator. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self registerForRemoteNotification];

    return YES;
}
    - (void)registerForRemoteNotification {
        if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            center.delegate = self;
            [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
                if( !error ){
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
    }
```

enable pushnotification in capabilities

Comment: center requestAuthorizationWithOptions: block can be called in non main thread if( !error ){dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [app registerForRemoteNotifications];
                     });}