# instanceID return nil in real device but wasn't nil in simulator in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

I using fcm for push notification.
I develop completely FCM on my project and i follow step by step of tutorial of firebase 
(my language is objective - c)
my device token is generated, but instanceID not generated !! in other words refreshToken Method not called ever !.
now when i run my project in simulator instanceID was generated. but when i run my project in real Device instanceID return null !! 
my time & date in real device is up to date but still not working !! it's log of my console when run project in simulator :

[log for simulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40d5K.jpg)

and this log when run my project in a real device :

```
2017-04-12 16:53:44.504 pin-Go[1031] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-04-12 16:53:44.546831+0430 pin-Go[1031:175957] APNs token retrieved: <f73de751 b71d59b8 f1e3b83a 826646ba d6338e7c a1a062be 4adda159 83cb5fa5>
2017-04-12 16:53:44.804239+0430 pin-Go[1031:175957] animating is complited ..
2017-04-12 16:53:44.804639+0430 pin-Go[1031:175957] animating is complited.
2017-04-12 16:53:45.124628+0430 pin-Go[1031:175957] animating1 ...
2017-04-12 16:53:45.751638+0430 pin-Go[1031:175957] Connected to FCM.
2017-04-12 16:53:45.755046+0430 pin-Go[1031:175957] InstanceID token: (null)
```

and my code is Exactly like this code : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m

and my log don't show any error for that ...
anyone can help me pls ??

Edit : That is my code :

```
  #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    @import UserNotifications;
    #endif
    @import GoogleMaps;
    @import GooglePlaces;
    #import "AfzayeshMojodiViewController.h"
    #import "ChangeInfoViewController.h"
    #import "MasirMontakhaViewController.h"
    @import Firebase;


    // Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
    // running iOS 10 and above. Implement FIRMessagingDelegate to receive data message via FCM for
    // devices running iOS 10 and above.
    #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    @interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
    @end
    #endif
    // Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
    #ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
    #define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
    #endif

    @implementation AppDelegate
    NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        self.urlStrWebService = [[NSString alloc] init];


        //Start of GCM
        // [START configure_firebase]
        [FIRApp configure];

        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
    #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
    #endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  return YES;
}     

//start implementing notification reciver :


//// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }


    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    // Print message ID.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    NSLog(@"%@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
//    // Won't connect since there is no token
//    if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
//        return;
//    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
            NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
            NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
     [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
    [self connectToFcm];
}

// [START connect_on_active]
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}
// [END connect_on_active]

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]


//end of implement notification.
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715368/ios-9-not-asking-permission-for-remote-notifications/42715503#42715503

Comment: @IOS_DEV not working ... :(